# JSF, Images from database and og:image integration

Tags: jsf, primefaces, facebook-opengraph

I' using JSF 2.2.12, Omnifaces 2.5.1 and PrimeFaces 6.

In our application we've decided to store images on the database, but we don't know in which way we can use the  with this approach.

If I use a static image,like the following, all is fine,

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://somePath/myImage.jpg" />
```

but with the images that come from the database we're not able to do the same.

Can you help us?

Thank you!

Comment: did you try something like `<img src="#{resource['images/someImages.png']}" />`

Comment: The image is not in the file system. It's stored in the database

Comment: It's useful when users share my page. Seems to be that Facebook reads the og:image tag as a image preview of the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement servlet which is read your file and do response.getOutputStream().write(content);
in the web page

```
<meta property="og:image" content="servletName?passImageId" />
```

example application here

<strike>https://github.com/armdev/jsf-web-app/blob/master/web-platform/src/main/java/com/project/web/handlers/PreviewImage.java</strike>

Comment: The link related to the example application is not working. Only the last brace is wrong

Comment: Hi, now its full work, just follow install instruction:)
https://github.com/armdev/jsf-web-app

Comment: I had the same idea but I wasn't sure was the best solution. Thank you